# New washing machine inlet valve (the one in the machine, not one on the wall pipe) sounds like it periodically leaks water inside, does it need a fix?

Tags: leak, washing-machine, valve

So I have bought a front loading LG washing machine and I sometimes notice a hum noise starts and it seems like water flows through the hose into the washing machine, but not always just from time to time, and I am talking about a washing machine that is even plugged off the wall (not sure if this matters). Note that the the water that leaks into is not seen in the washing machine drum, so I am not sure what happens. However it seems like this might cause mold to grow up inside the washing machine, so I am interested in fixing this, maybe it is smart to call warranty service but does anyone know how to fix this, is it a tedious process and also can this really cause mold to grow up if it never reaches the drum, from my understandings if a decent amount of water is leaked it will catch up into the drum, but let me know if I miss something from a technical aspect of how the water valve inside the washer or how the whole process of water reaching the drum works.

Comment: How do you know there is water if you don’t see any in the drum? A water hammer event (small one) can make noises in the plumbing system that do not harm anything, the cause of the noise could be from a different tap all together, since you have no evidence of water flow other than noise. A valve that is stuck open with power off will usually continue to leak and there would be evidence, once these valves are closed they don’t start leaking later unless the system pressure is well above the valves pressure rating (usually in the 90-100psi range or more).

Comment: Because I hear humming noise from that hose happening right at the connection and then a dripping noise in the washing machine (but not in the drum), I will wait for a day or two now without using it and try to have a spin only cycle which is supposed to drain the water at first and this will show me if there was water inside the washing machine.

Comment: I had had several front loaders all of them lave left some water, my current one has a clean out prior to the pump maybe a pint of water exits when I clean that filter out , if you have a clean out it may be a way to see if it is leaking , however if the water pressure is spiking and the valve is opening you may have other issues

Comment: @EdBeal Hey, for now I diagnosed when it happens - as it is not so random. It has to do with the pressure, all the taps in my house are under one main line, whenever one goes ON the pressure is halved I have measured this in the past and without anything running I have about 6 bars, so I guess pretty normal. Anyways whenever a tap goes on the leakage starts, it drips tears of water into the washing machine and I heard the valve opening. Anyways I also have not mentioned that I have two washing machines connected with an Y split valve, the other one doesn't have this problem. Recommendations?

Comment: If the valve is leaking from lack of pressure it may be pretty pilot actuated, 6 bar is much higher than normal pressure for most homes in the US, (normally closer to 4 bar) with the low pressure point being close to 3 bar. The valves are normally fail safe with springs to keep them closed even with low pressure so I would say it is a defective valve if dripping with low pressure even if pilot actuated.

Comment: Can you explain a bit further on pilot actuated and how it works? Also, how hard is to replace that part from the washing machine? I will later today or tomorrow check on how much water will it drain on spin mode.

Comment: @EdBeal I might've diagnose this one, when the pressure in the house changes (from water going off/on) the actual hose does this weird friction noise from the tiles that sounds like water dripping - I think this is the cause. However, I also noticed that when the machine is moved some water can be felt. I don't know if this is normal or not.